# Save Image From URL To Clipboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uipasteboard

I am trying to save an image from a URL to the clipboard. I tried using:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fromURL];
NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
[pasteboard setData:imageData forPasteboardType:@"kUTTypeJPEG"]; //is kUTTypeJPEG even the right type?
```

but it does not work. It does not give a warning, error or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

For saving image to clipboard :

[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].image = someImage;

To get the image out again from clipboard :

UIImage *someImage = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].image;

Comment: Ok, I will try it as soon as I get back home (around 4:30). Thank you.